# Window, how to override maximize?

Tags: wpf, window

When the user tries to maximize , i need it to maximize to a fixed width and height, not the whole screen.

Comment: Setting the Windows MaxHeight, MaxWidth properties had no effect on maximize?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold: That works; I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties.